# client32.exe process - high cpu usage

Tags: windows-xp, process

My Win Xp computer has a process (client32.exe) that consumes a lot of cpu (between 38% to 70%). Is there a way to identify what is the cause for such high consumption? the computer is quite old and not very powerful (celeron cpu and 1GB ram). I used Process Explorer and did not find more information.

Comment: It's not a standard process, AFAIK. What's the path to the executable? (You should be able to find out with Task Manager or Process Explorer.)

Comment: Windows XP is no longer supported, maybe it is time to upgrade? there is a high chance that this is malware of some sort.

Comment: Where is the `client32.exe` file actually stored? Did you try scanning it using [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) already?